# writing byte array data into csv file

Tags: c#, image, file, csv

I have a byte array which I am trying to write into a csv file.Something like this

```
string second=image.ToString();
string csv = string.Format("{0},{1}\n", first,second);
File.AppendAllText(filePath, csv);
```

where image is byte array.When I am trying to write in a file it shows system.byte[] instead of the byte array.How can I write the actual data.

Comment: csv is a text file, don't write binary data into it.

Comment: To write bytes to a file you can use [File.WriteAllBytes](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=File.WriteAllBytes&emptyWatermark=true&ac=4), but @I4V is right saying that csv file is for text, why put binary data?

Comment: CSV stands for "comma separated values" what is your strategy to prevent one of the bytes being 0x2c, which corresponds to your comma delimiter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code

```
File.AppendAllText(filePath, BitConverter.ToString(image));
```

Hope this is what you are expecting.